# Django trigger python script through HTML button

Tags: python, html, django

Im trying to execute a python script by clicking a button on my html code. I want the submit button to trigger the python script and whatever is submitted in the submit box will be added to the python script

Views

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "Vote/test.html"  

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return redirect(reverse_lazy("Vote:Test"))
```

Test.html

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fullname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

name.py

```
print "Hi there %s " %test.html
```

Comment: How long does the script take to run? If its returns almost immediately, run it from your view. If you need it to run in the background as it takes a while, you will need to look at Celery or something to run it asynchronously.

Comment: @wobbily_col Would i just copy the code underneath my def post? It is a fairly short code

Comment: I think so, thought its difficult to tell without seeing it. Is it set up as a module that out can call from other python code? (You will need to use an import statement to import the module).